# putting a date into a temp table in US format

Tags: php, mysql

OK so my code makes a temp table, with a date field, and then gets data from several tables to write into the temp table.

The date in the cruises table is a datetime field and has the day month year and time.

I want to write the temp table with just the date, in US format...

```
    $maketemp = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp(`sailingId` int NOT NULL,
        `live` varchar(1), `ship` varchar(20), `code` varchar(5), `title` varchar(255), 
        `sailDate` date,`fromport` varchar(255), `nights` varchar(3), `type` varchar(30), 
        `fare` varchar(5), `offerFare` varchar(5),`deposit` varchar(5))"; 

mysql_query( $maketemp, $connection ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error ( ) );

$inserttemp = "INSERT INTO temp SELECT cruises.id AS sailingId, live, cruises.ship AS ship, 
        cruises.code AS code, cruises.title AS title, DATE_FORMAT(cruises.departs, '%m-%d-%y') AS sailDate,
        cruises.fromport AS fromport, cruises.duration AS nights, fares_usa.type AS type,
        fares_usa.fare AS fare, fares_usa.offered AS offerFare, supplements_usa.deposit AS 
        deposit FROM cruises, fares_usa, supplements_usa WHERE live ='Y' AND 
        cruises.id = fares_usa.cruise_id AND fares_usa.cruise_id = supplements_usa.cruise_id";

mysql_query( $inserttemp, $connection ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error ( ) );
```

Right now when this comes out as CSV, the date field is either 0000-00-00 or a wrong date in the past like 13-Mar-2001

I'm a bit stuck..

Rich :)

Comment: temp.sailDate has to be a varchar type and not date type

Answer (score 0):

Check the [date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) documentation or just format it using PHP.

Comment: can you explain why this should help in this case?